# continue instead of return inside a function in C++`

Tags: c++, c++11, return, continue

Does it make sense to use `continue` instead of `return`, while completing a function in C++?

```
void function()
{
  //do something;
  continue; //instead of return
}
```

Comment: What would `continue` in that context mean? Continue where, what?

Comment: Yes it does: `#define continue return` - *runs and hides...*

Comment: You also don't need to put a return as the last statement of a void function. It will return automatically.

Comment: Actually, yes you can do that. If in the function block, you write your body as `do { /* function body */ } while(0);`. Hope this helps

Comment: @SathishKrishnan If you really want to delete your question you can look at [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that), basically you will need to flag your question for moderator attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `continue` can be only used inside `while`, `for`, or `do`.

Comment: And then, only as a means of obfuscation.  (In over 25 years of C++, I've never used `continue`.)